# MUI: Do not close Menu when clicked on disabled MenuItem

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a code like:

```
<Menu>
  <MenuItem disabled> Disabled </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem> Enabled </MenuItem>
<Menu>
```

I want to keep a menu opened when I click on the disabled `MenuItem`. Is there a relatively easy way to do it?

I tried adding `onClick={(e)=> {e.stopPropagation()}}, but it did not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the disabled attribute should be enough.

Can you check the following [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-tess-g7f493?file=/index.js) to validate that you use the right structure to build the Menu?

Comment: you are right, I was using the menu in the wrong way, figured it out. thank you